# php dateTime logic error?

Tags: php, datetime

I'm programming a rudimentary clock and calendar for an ongoing table-top rpg being played on discord. The time in-game moves twice as fast as real time. The game is set in Detroit. The GM has ruled that 25/02/2017 in the real world equates to 25/08/2008 in the game world.
There are two problems that I know of in my code.

1. It may end up skipping even-numbered days. I haven't been able to verify this yet.
2. The clock appears to be working as expected, but the date is coming back about eight days fast.

Any feedback is appreciated.

```
<?php
//game start and current date
$start = new DateTime('2017-02-25T00:00:00.000000Z');
echo $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "\r\n";
$current = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Detroit') );
echo $current->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "\r\n";
//find the difference
$difference = $start->diff($current);
echo $difference->format('%R%a days');
echo "\r\n";

//take the starting time in-game
$d = new DateTime('2008-08-25T00:00:00.000000Z');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//add the difference twice to get current gameTime
$d->add($difference);
$d->add($difference);
echo "\r\n";

// Output the date with microseconds.
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "\r\n";

?>
```

Comment: **It may end up skipping even-numbered days** means?

Comment: Why do you think that it may end up skipping even numbered days?

Comment: Alright, never-mind. It does not skip even numbered days. It's just running eight days fast.